# Converting between timezones without affecting the actual time?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to store and retreive a date object that is supposed to remain consistant on saving regardless of whatever timezone the browser is set to.

For example. I have a 7PM IST which when converted with an offset should return to 7 PM of a timezone that I select. 
I then want to be able to retreive the same timestamp as 7 PM of whatever timezone the browser is in.

I have figured out the first part

```
var date = moment(date);
var localDate = date.clone();
localDate.tz(timezone); // continent/city from momentjs
localDate.tz(timezone);
localDate.add(date.utcOffset() - localDate.utcOffset(), 'minutes');
localDate.toDate();
```

which ultimately gives me the date and I can use to save into the database as UTC ( I am saving it in mongodb)

I am not sure on how I can reverse it back to the local timezone so that I can get the return value as 7PM of the browsers timezone.

Comment: Once you save the date in UTC, you no longer have the source offset. So to convert it back to the same time in target time zone, you will need to capture the source offset so that you can convert it back to source offset time and then offset the difference with target timezone. Btw having the same time in different time zones can lead to ambiguity when time zone rule changes or zones with day light savings.

Comment: ECMAScript Date objects are UTC, it's the host that has the offset. If you have 7pm in a particular time zone and change the time zone to one with a different offset, then the time should change. Otherwise it represents a different moment in time.

Answer (score 0):

convert the date into UTC format before you save to db

```
moment.utc()
```

Whenever you retrive convert from UTC to local time.

```
moment.utc(utcDateTime, utcDateTimeFormat).local().format(specifiedFormat)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I need to store the dates in mongodb as the date object.

Comment: i have update the ans. Let me know if that solves your purpose